# Print the addresses of all the bytes occupied by an integer variable

Tags: c, memory-address, void-pointers

Here's the code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char character_1 = '0';
    int integer_1 = 12321;
    char character_2 = '1';
    char character_3 = '2';

    printf("Integer occupies %zu byte(s) of space.\n",sizeof(int));
    printf("Address of Integer 1: %p\n",(void*)&integer_1);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Character occupies %zu byte(s) of space.\n",sizeof(char));
    printf("Address of Character 1: %p\n",(void*)&character_1);
    printf("Address of Character 2: %p\n",(void*)&character_2);
    printf("Address of Character 3: %p\n",(void*)&character_3);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and, the generated output -

```
Integer occupies 4 byte(s) of space.
Address of Integer 1: 000000000061FE18

Character occupies 1 byte(s) of space.
Address of Character 1: 000000000061FE1F
Address of Character 2: 000000000061FE17
Address of Character 3: 000000000061FE16
```

I want to **print the addresses of all the four bytes of space** occupied by the integer variable **`integer_1`**, which means print all four of these - `000000000061FE18`, `000000000061FE19`, `000000000061FE1A` and `000000000061FE1B`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int integer_1 = 12321;
    unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)&integer_1;
    
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(int); i++){
        printf("Address: %p -> Value: %02hhx\n", p+i, *(p+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: As pointed out by KPCT, working with `void*` is indeed possible, just a bit more tedious if you are also interested in the value pointed, and not the address only.

For example, adapting my above solution to use void*, would result in something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int integer_1 = 12321;
    void* p = (void*)&integer_1;
    
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(int); i++){
        printf("Address: %p -> Value: %02hhx\n", p+i, *((char*) p+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

where you would have to go through the cast to char* anyway

Answer (score 1):

You would need to cast the `int` pointer to a `char` pointer (or an `int8_t` pointer), then step through each of the bytes, something like this:

```
char *cp = (char*)&integer_1;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(integer_1); ++i)
    printf("Address of integer_1, byte %d: %p\n",i,cp++);
```

Comment: not really, You can do it by `void* p = &int` as well.

Comment: @KPCT the problem with void pointers is that pointer arithmetic is not allowed by the C standard, it might work depending on the compiler you are using but it's not a way-to-go solution

Comment: @ozerodb??? when did this get in place? have been using `void *` w arithmetic for quite a while, multiple compilers and architectures. If I am not mistaken that is one of the reasons why you do not cast output of `malloc()` to anything.

Comment: @KPCT I'll take a look at the standard again, but I remember there were some limitations with using void pointers

Comment: @ozerodb that is one thing I loved about `void *` you are not bound by type.

Comment: @KPCT I edited my answer to take into account the usage of void*, though a cast to something is always required if you want to access the value pointed and not the address itself (or am I missing something? feel free to edit if needed)

Comment: @KPCT: ozerodb’s statement is somewhat incorrect. The C standard **allows** arithmetic with `void *` (because it does not prohibit it, although it does require a warning or other diagnostic message), but it does not define it. If you have been using arithmetic on `void *`, you are likely using a compiler extension which defines arithmetic on `void *` as if it were a pointer to a character type. (And it is an unnecessary extension, as using a pointer to a character type would suffice.) “I have been using [something]” is not a reason to believe it is defined by the C standard.

Comment: @KPCT: Specifically, C 2018 6.5.6 2 and 3 require pointer operands to `+` and `-` to be pointers to a complete object type, and, per 6.2.5 19, `void` is an incomplete type that cannot be completed. 6.5.6 2 and 3 are in a Constraints section, so a violation of them requires a diagnostic message.

Comment: @EricPostpischil tnx always glad when I can learn something, most of the time I have been using `gcc` but I have also used MIPS compilers, and some others, I do not remember, but `void *` used to be ultimate force :). Once again thank you, I will try to remeber this.